# How can I force my parent ViewController to reload after unwinding from a child?

Tags: ios, ios6, segue

I have a parent VC, I want to visit a child, and after having visited the child, I want the user to press the back button in the Navbar. When the parent VC is displayed, I would like it to refresh so it shows changes made in the child.

During the unwind I want to pass back an array, so want to display information from that array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the refreshing code in viewDidAppear in the ViewController then it should be called any time that the ViewController is displayed. Therefore, it will be shown initially, and after the back button is pressed.

This is different than placing it in viewDidLoad, which will only be called the first time the ViewController is loaded.

Comment: Thanks. What the code line would you recommend to make the refresh? Thanks!

Comment: Do you currently have the code to display the information from the array? If so, you could move that code to viewDidAppear. If not, I'd have to see your code to give any specific advice.

Comment: I've not gotten so far yet;) I want to use the array to retrieve information from a CoreData Entity and display the results in a UITableView on the ViewController.

Comment: Since you are using a UITableView, if you set things up right then you could use UITableView reloadData in viewWillAppear. Before that, you need to bind the data to the TableView. Is the array the data, or does information in the array point you to the right data from CoreData?

Comment: The information in the array will be used to create a second array with information from coredata. Basically, I'm passing back an itemID and need to get the itemTitle to display in a tableview

Comment: So then you just need to use that new array in your cellForRowAtIndexPath. Simple!

Comment: I'll give it a try! I'm already seeing the updated data in viewDidLoad. It's already a feat as I'm getting it from an unwindsegue... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: So yes, I've implemented the new array, it's gathering its data in a method called from viewDidAppear and it's in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but the tableView is not updating. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out - needed to reference my table. Hallelujah - it's taken me a day, but it's working correctly. Many thanks for your help.